# Filter vector of 1s and -1s in R

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I would like to apply several filters to the following vector:

```
v <-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1-1,1,1,1)
```

The filters I would like to apply should remove 1s among -1s and vice versa. The filters should be for 3, 4, 5 then 6 elements as follows:

(-1,1,-1)       to (-1,-1,-1)

(1,-1,1)        to (1,1,1)

(-1, 1, 1, -1)  to (-1, -1, -1, -1)

(1,-1,-1, 1)    to (1, 1, 1, 1)

(-1, 1, 1, 1, -1)  to (-1, -1, -1, -1, -1)

(1, -1, -1, -1, 1)    to (1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

(-1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1)  to (-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)

(1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1)    to (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

I used first for-loop then tried to vectorize the loops using paste and gsub (please see the full example below)

However, the vectorized version doesn't produce the same result as the for-loop (as it doesn't consider the changes occurred in one step in the following one)

Is there a vectorized version of that code that actually does the same effect as the for-loop?

---

A complete example of the two of using for-loop vs paste and gsub:

```
v <-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1-1,1,1,1)
t1 <- v
t2 <- v
```

-1  1 -1 to -1 -1 -1

```
for (i in 2:(length(t1)-1)) {
        if (t1[i-1]==-1 & t1[i+1]==-1 & t1[i]==1){
                t1[i] <- -1   
        } 
}
```

1 -1  1 to   1   1   1

```
for (i in 2:(length(t1)-1)) {
        if (t1[i-1]==1 & t1[i+1]==1 & t1[i]==-1){
                t1[i] <- 1
        } 
}
```

-1  1  1 -1 to -1 -1 -1 -1

```
for (i in 3:(length(t1)-1)) {
        if (t1[i-2]==-1 & t1[i+1]==-1 & t1[i]==1 & t1[i-1] ==1) {
                t1[i]   <- -1
                t1[i-1] <- -1
        }
}
```

1 -1 -1  1 to  1  1  1  1

```
for (i in 3:(length(t1)-1)) {
        if (t1[i-2]==1 & t1[i+1]==1 & t1[i]==-1 & t1[i-1] ==-1) {
                t1[i]   <- 1
                t1[i-1] <- 1
        }
}
```

-1  1  1  1 -1 to -1 -1 -1 -1 -1

```
for (i in 4:(length(t1)-1)) {
        if (t1[i-3]==-1 & t1[i+1]==-1 & t1[i-2]==1 & t1[i-1] ==1 & t1[i] ==1) {
                t1[i-2]   <- -1
                t1[i-1]   <- -1
                t1[i]     <- -1
        }
}
```

1 -1 -1 -1  1 to  1  1  1  1  1

```
for (i in 4:(length(t1)-1)) {
        if (t1[i-3]==1 & t1[i+1]==1 & t1[i-2]==-1 & t1[i-1] ==-1 & t1[i] ==-1) {
                t1[i-2]   <- 1
                t1[i-1]   <- 1
                t1[i]     <- 1
        }
}
```

-1  1  1  1  1 -1 to -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1

```
for (i in 5:(length(t1)-1)) {
        if (t1[i-4]==-1 & t1[i+1]==-1 & t1[i-3]==1 & t1[i-2]==1 & t1[i-1] ==1 & t1[i] ==1) {
                t1[i-3]   <- -1
                t1[i-2]   <- -1
                t1[i-1]   <- -1
                t1[i]     <- -1
        }
}
```

1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 to  1  1  1  1  1  1

```
for (i in 5:(length(t1)-1)) {
        if (t1[i-4]==1 & t1[i+1]==1 & t1[i-3]==-1 & t1[i-2]==-1 & t1[i-1] ==-1 & t1[i] ==-1) {
                t1[i-3]   <- 1
                t1[i-2]   <- 1
                t1[i-1]   <- 1
                t1[i]     <- 1
        }
}
```

Now the vectorized gsub version:

```
t2 <- paste(v, collapse="")
```

-1  1 -1 to -1 -1 -1

```
t2 <- gsub("-11-1", "-1-1-1", t2)
```

1 -1  1 to   1   1   1

```
t2 <- gsub("1-11", "111", t2)
```

-1  1  1 -1 to -1 -1 -1 -1

```
t2 <- gsub("-111-1", "-1-1-1-1", t2)
```

1 -1 -1  1 to  1  1  1  1

```
t2 <- gsub("1-1-11", "1111", t2)
```

-1  1  1  1 -1 to -1 -1 -1 -1 -1

```
t2 <- gsub("-1111-1", "-1-1-1-1-1", t2)
```

1 -1 -1 -1  1 to  1  1  1  1  1

```
t2 <- gsub("1-1-1-11", "11111", t2)
```

-1  1  1  1  1 -1 to -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1

```
t2 <- gsub("-11111-1", "-1-1-1-1-1-1", t2)
```

1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 to  1  1  1  1  1  1

```
t2 <- gsub("1-1-1-1-11", "111111", t2)

t2 <-as.integer(strsplit(t2, "(?<=\\d)", perl = TRUE)[[1]])
all.equal(t1, t2)
```

[1] "Mean relative difference: 2"

Comment: e.g. `t[t==1] <- -1`. BTW, `t` is not a good variable name. Try `?t`.

Comment: Your loops are modifying your data in place. They might not be doing exactly what you expect...

Comment: Could you please add an example where the for loop does not match the vectorized solution with `paste`? For the vector you provided, the output of the first for loop exactly matches the vectorized solution. Therefore, you haven't provided a reproducible example of your problem yet.

Comment: Simon: I changed that already to v, t1 and t2
James: that is he idea, to use the change in a set of elements in the following loop steps
josilber: You are right, I am still struggling with gaining good habits in that matter. I added a complete example at the end of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate this to Rcpp easily:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector myfilter(IntegerVector x) {
  for (int i = 1; i < (x.size() - 1); i++) {
    if (x(i-1) == -1 && x(i+1) == -1 && x(i) == 1) {
      x(i) = -1;
    }    
  }

  for (int i = 2; i < (x.size() - 1); i++) {
    if (x(i-2) == -1 && x(i-1) == 1 && x(i+1) == -1 && x(i) == 1) {
      x(i) = -1;
      x(i-1) = -1;
    }    
  }  
   return x;
}
```

Testing it in R:

```r
t1 <- myfilter(t)

for (i in 2:(length(t)-1)) {
  if (t[i-1]==-1 & t[i+1]==-1 & t[i]==1){
    t[i] <- -1   
  } 
}

for (i in 3:(length(t)-1)) {
  if (t[i-2]==-1 & t[i+1]==-1 & t[i]==1 & t[i-1] ==1) {
    t[i]   <- -1
    t[i-1] <- -1
  }
}

all.equal(t, t1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you Roland! It took me a while to understand that the code you wrote is in C++, which is actually a brilliant idea! I am trying to apply the code, but need first to understand Rcpp and C++ basics (which could help me a lot in my project)